im trying to run some very basic javascript on a click event and im getting an undefined function error


<script>
  function x() {
    console.log("thisWorks")
  }
</script>
<button onclick="x()"></button>



my hopes were that clicking the button would trigger the console command and i could add more code, but when i click it i get an error that looks like this error message
im using opera GX browser about:blank page.
I checked w3schools and copied directly from their page, where it worked, i still got the error. (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick)
i tried moving the functions before the button element, i tried putting the script in the parent element of the button, i tried copying from the html in the w3schools page and it's the same error.
honestly im a very novice coder and it's probably something stupid but i would appreciate some help
edit: i asked a friend to do the same thing on their computer with the same result, so it's not my pc.
i have no clue why this works in the stack overflow preview but not in about:blank

You need to add ("") around the thisWorks word. like this: console.log ("thisWorks")


<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script>
         function x() {
         console.log ("thisWorks")
         }
      </script>
      <button onclick="x()">Click Me!</button>
   </body>
</html>




thanks, i still get the same error about x though
